# Macbook Air - No Apple logo but still boots

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have been looking all day for an answer to this so I thought I would pick your brains :)

Macbook Air 4,1 (Mid 2011) 11 inch, i5, 2gb RAM.

After pressing the power button, I hear the Apple "chime".  The screen stays black.  10 Seconds later, I get the login screen for OSX.  This doesn't seem like a problem but I wanted to do Apple Diagnostics, boot from other drives etc and now I can't, because I can't see the initial Apple screen.

Just upgraded to El Capitan to see if it would fix the problem.  It didn't.

edit: I have also tried resetting NVRAM and the SMC to no avail.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Comment: To be clear: holding down the keys for those functions at the correct times (regardless of display) doesn't work at all?

Comment: Correct.  I get the repeated chimes (for the NVRAM), but that doesn't fix it.  I have done this multiple times, along with the SMC keypress.  If i hold down another set of keys (e.g. Internet Restore) the device stays on a black screen.